# how to put all docx data into separate dataframe columns in python

Tags: python, arrays, regex, dataframe, numpy

I didnt find anything for this question in stackoverflow, so please be patient with me and i didnt get any idea to work this out, please bear with me.

Below is my code:

```
v_doc 

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(paths):
    for t in files:
        if t.endswith('.xlsx'):   
            v_doc.append(Document(t))

            # say like, there are 3 docx which contains simple sentences. how to put 
            #those sentences into seperate dataframe columns for each docx sentences ? i have many docx. n number of docx
```

example docx:

docx1 contains:

```
Hello guys how are you all, hope you guys doing good.
```

docx2 contains:

```
I dont know what to write here
```

docx3 contains:

```
We are strong together ! do we ?
```

expected output:

```
dataframe:
column1                                                 column2
#Hello guys how are you all, hope you guys doing good.  #I don't know what to write here
column3
#We are strong together ! do we ?
```

hope i get some response. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is not a minimal reproducible code snippet--try to make it reproducible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gotchya:

```py
import os
import docx

dataframe = {}

def get_files(extension, location):
    v_doc = []

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(location):
        for t in files:
            if t.endswith(extension):   
                v_doc.append(t)
    return v_doc

file_list = get_files('.docx', '.')
index = 0
for file in file_list:
    index += 1
    doc = docx.Document(file)
    column_label = f'column{index}'
    data_content = doc.paragraphs[0].text
    dataframe = {column_label: data_content}

print(dataframe)
```

Comment: {'column1': 'contents of example1.docx', 'column2': 'contents of example2.docx', 'column3': 'contents of example3.docx'}

Comment: doc.paragraphs[0].text showing nothing. but       for x in data_content:
                                                                                    print(x.text)

Comment: It is supposed to grab the `title` only. i.e. the very first paragraph. If it is left blank then so it will too.

Comment: oh i see but is it possible to grab all things in docx1, docx2 and puting in column1 and column2 of dataframe ?

Comment: doc.paragraphs[0].text shows nothing dude, but doc.paragraphs.text after iteration shows the content

Comment: if you need all the contents inside of the `docx` ,  then join the `paragraphs` all together with two new lines: (one to start a new line and another to start a new paragraph) that can be achieved using `join` like this `doc.paragraphs.join('\n\n')`

Comment: AttributeError: 'Paragraph' object has no attribute 'join'. ...

Comment: can you please update working code in your main code ? thank you for trying to help, really appreciate.

Comment: Working awesome !!!! changed little bit of code. MANY MANY THANKS !

Comment: Hey, i tried this dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data_content , columns=[column_label]) and the dataframe only showing column2 but not column1 can you help ?

Comment: Of course, it did not. You have just squeezed all the `data_content` into a single column named by the value of `column_label`. `dataframe`  is already of the data type `dataframe`. I see no value recasting it using `pd.DataFrame`. i.e. use `dataframe['some_nice_column']` as it is wherever needed.

Comment: yeah i understand but dataframe.to_excel is very easy one. can you please tell how to export that {column_label: data_content} as excel.xlsx

Comment: Do I get "Best Answer" XD XD? 1. `df = dataframe['some_nice_column']` and 2. `df.to_excel("output.xlsx")`

Comment: Hey buddy i understand but the columns should be 'n' number of columns because the docx file are not just two files but n no of files in my case.

Comment: hey i gave your response as best answer no doubt in that !!!

Comment: can you please help with this query ? i will give 50+ reputation if answered. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68413792/how-to-sort-dataframe2-according-to-dataframe1-with-fuzzywuzzy

Comment: You got it... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68413792/how-to-sort-dataframe2-according-to-dataframe1-with-fuzzywuzzy/68425166